# Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 5 activities and the flow is like this

> 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5

at the 5th activity, upon pressing the back button, is it possible to get back to activity 2 or 3 wihtout finishing any activity? Currently I only get to the 4th one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to get 2 or 3 u want to write code on back Key

```
@Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) {

          if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           Intent i=new Intent(getbaseapplicationcontext(),activity2.class)
                    startActivity(i)
              return true;

          }
          return super.onKeyDown(i, event);
        }
```

And another way is

u want to finish Activity whatever u doesnot want to
As u need here Activity4

Comment: @Parag , when am start new activity in back button, it will not have the back animation,ie my problem

Comment: @parag what if he again presses back after coming 2 actuivity 2.:-P.

Comment: the swiping direction is different for when we start an activity and resumes the activity

Comment: @parag but would not he again directed 2 activity 5 after pressing back button on activity 2.

Comment: To do this properly, have a look at the documents about the "Back Stack". Here's the main doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html. This solution is, in my opinion, too hackish.

Answer (score 2):

There's something like `ActivityHistory` . I am not very sure about the exact keyword, but there does exist something like that. You can traverse through it.

Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html) link helps!

Comment: A bit more precise: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Thank you, espinchi, maybe this post is added pretty recently. I never saw it being there when I used to visit it

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem can be, simply override the Back hard button, and then start whichever activity you want to start. But overriding the default behavior is not recommended.
Revert back for any query.

Comment: When we start  an activity, can we add the animation ,ie similar to when we resumes the activity using back button

Answer (score 0):

When a new activity starts, it is pushed onto the back stack and takes user focus. The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" stack mechanism, so, when the user is done with the current activity and presses the Back button, it is popped from the stack (and destroyed) and the previous activity resumes.
On Back Button Pressed.

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) {

      if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( YourActivity.this, New Activity.class );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity( intent );
          return true;

      }
      return super.onKeyDown(i, event);
    }
```